# How can I bind Foreground to a property

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't bind foreground color to property...

I have this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="150" Margin="10,5" 
         IsReadOnly="True" Name="Output" FontSize="20" Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}"/>
```

and:

```
private Brush foregroundColor;

public Brush ForegroundColor {
    get { return foregroundColor; }
    set {
        foregroundColor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");
    }
}

private void CheckBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (IsPalindrome(Input.Text)) {
        ForegroundColor = Brushes.Gold;
        Output.Text = "Yep";                
    } else 
        Output.Text = "Nope";
}
```

I'm just a beginner, so it is a simple project ;)
Some sources to learn from are welcome...
sorry for mistakes, i'm from Ukraine

Comment: Is the `DataContext` set to an instance of the class that contains the `ForegroundColor` property?

Comment: missed it... just learning how it works..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined that property in your code behind class, you can set the `DataContext` of your window this way:

```
<Window x:Class="YourWindow"
  Title="Your Title"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

After that your should be able to bind that property as your are trying to do.